# How does the below code create an array with a all random numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, apply

I know the below code can be used to create a large array of random numbers, but I don't exactly know how it works. Can someone explain this step by step?

```
Array.apply(null, {length: 100000}).map(Function.call, Math.random)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. create an array of 5 items, where each item is 'undefined'.

```
let temp = Array.apply(null, {length: 5});
```

2. map over the [undefined, undefined, undefined...] array, and replace each 'undefined' with the result of Math.random();

```
temp.map(() => { return Math.random() });
```

As this is a function returning a function you can use shorten it to be:

```
temp.map(Math.random);
```

3. `Function.call` is not needed.